# MongoDB - orderby syntax breaks statement

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The following query works until I add the orderby statement, but when I try to run after adding it an exception is thrown

```
db.games.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$games"},
{$project: {_id: 0, year: {$substr: ["$join_date", 0, 4]},
           status: 1,
            games: 1}},
{$match: {status: {$ne: "disabled"}}},
{$group: {_id: {"Year": "$year", code: "$games.code"}, "AverageWins": {$avg: "$games.wins"}}},
{$orderby: {"AverageWins": -1}}


])
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: It's [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) NOT `$orderby`. The latter is a ["cursor modifer"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/) and "deprecated" since MongoDB 3.2. Not that it was ever a valid aggregation pipeline stage anyway.

Comment: You might also read [Aggregation Pipeline Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/) since your `$project` has no real benefit here. MongoDB aggregation pipelines don't require you to be as "terse" as SQL does. The "SELECT" is implied within `$group`.

Comment: Thanks Neil Lunn, that fixed it